# How to use nginx or apache to process tcp inbound traffic and redirect to specific php processor?

Tags: tcp, nginx

This is the main idea, I want to use NGINX or Apache webservers as a tcp processor, so they manage all threads and connections and client sockets, all packets received from a port, lets say,  port 9000 will be redirected to a program made on php or python, and that program will process each request, storing the data in a database. The big problem is also that this program needs to send data to the client or socket that is currently connecting to the NGINX or Apache server, I've been told that I should do something like this instead of creating my own TCP server, which is too difficult and is very hard to maintain since the socket communication with huge loads could lead in memory faults or even could crash down the server. I have done it before, and in fact the server crashed.
Any ideas how to achieve this ??
thanks.

Comment: Apache and nginx are http servers, are you really looking for plain tcp server instead of http server? I suspect that both apache and nginx will discard any incoming non-http traffic.

Comment: I think that both servers has the capability of processing any other information type besides http, for example in apache, its process all incoming tcp packets and it has a bundled http 1.0 / 1.1 module that parse all incoming traffic with http headers, if you disable that, you could have apache just receiving traffic no matter if its http type or any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache/ nginx is web server and could be used to provide static content service to your cusomter and forwarding the application service requests to other application servers.

i only knows about django and here is sample configuration of nginx from  [Configuration for Django, Apache and Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888562/configuration-for-django-apache-and-nginx)

```
location / {
       # proxy / requests to apache running django on port 8081
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
       proxy_redirect     off;
}
location /media/ { 
    # serve static media directly from nginx
    root   /srv/anuva_project/www/;
    expires 30d;
    break;
}
```

Based on this configuration, the nginx access local static data for url under /media/*
and forward requests to django server located at localhost port 8018.

Comment: Seems to be almost what I'm looking for, is there any way to send information from in this case an app in 8081 to a specific client using specific socket managed by nginx ?? or just nginx redirect the traffic and makes a shutdown in the active socket after receiving the packet??

Comment: seems nginx only acts as a transparent proxy for TCP connection between client and application server

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling HAProxy is certainly a tool better suited for your needs, which have to do with TCP and not HTTP apparently. You should at least give it a try.